# Не выходит в golang присвоить элементу в map из указателей на структуру указатель на структуру с данными

Tags: golang, map, struct

Коллеги выручайте - голову уже сломал.. Есть вот такая конструкция из структур:

```
type StructZapros struct {
    IdP       int
    IdZ       int
    Name_pole string
    Mask      string
    Iduser    int
}
type TemplStructZapros struct {
    IdZ      int
    Zaproses map[int]*StructZapros
}
```

Вот так пытаюсь заполнить для отправления в Template:

```
var StructZes TemplStructZapros
vars := mux.Vars(r)
idZ := vars["id"]
StructZes.IdZ, _ = strconv.Atoi(idZ)
rows, err := database.Query("select * from StructZapros where idZ =$1 ", idZ)
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
}
defer rows.Close()

for rows.Next() {
    p := new(StructZapros)
    err := rows.Scan(&p.IdP, &p.IdZ, &p.Name_pole, &p.Mask, &p.Iduser)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        continue
    }
    StructZes.Zaproses[p.IdP] = p //// вот тут ошибка
```

при попытке присвоения получаю ошибку "assignment to entry in nil map" я догадываюсь, что дело в пустом мапе, но попытка добавить строку

```
StructZes.Zaproses[p.IdP] = new(StructZapros)
```

результата не дает. Что я не так делаю?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создайте сам объект и карту в нем. Примерно так:

```
StructZes := new(TemplStructZapros)
StructZes.Zaproses := make(map[int]*StructZapros)
```

Или так:

```
StructZes := TemplStructZapros{
    Zaproses: make(map[int]*StructZapros),
}
```

Для карт и каналов только объявить переменную (как для примитивных типов и слайсов) недостаточно.

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное!!! Все заработало!